# HTML Form output styling

Tags: php, html, forms, email, layout

So I have created a simple form that when submitted, gets sent to my email address. At the moment I am not happy with the formatting of the email. As there is going to be quite a lot of information being inputted, it can be hard to read.

Here is the section of the php that sends to my email

```
$body_message .= 'Title: '.$field_title."\n";
$body_message .= 'Full Name: '.$field_fullname."\n";
$body_message .= 'Company Name: '.$field_companyname."\n";
$body_message .= 'Company Registered Number: '.$field_companynumber."\n";
$body_message .= 'Address: '.$field_address."\n";
$body_message .= 'Postcode: '.$field_postcode."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone Number: '.$field_phonenumber."\n";
$body_message .= 'Email Address: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Mobile Number: '.$field_mobile."\n";
$body_message .= 'Website URL: '.$field_website."\n \n \n";

$body_message .= 'NEED: '.$field_NEED."\n \n";
$body_message .= 'APPROACH: '.$field_APPROACH."\n \n";
$body_message .= 'BENEFITS: '.$field_BENEFITS."\n \n";
$body_message .= 'COMPETITION: '.$field_COMPETITION."\n \n";
```

At the moment, the email i receive looks something like this:

Title: Mr 
Full Name: A Name 
Company Name: A Company 
etc....

I would like it to look like this 
Title:
Mr
Full Name:
My Name
Company Name:
A Company
etc...

and possible even have the 'Title:' 'Full Name:' 'Comany Name:' in bold or a different colour.

Thanks in advance, Tom

========================================================================

Answer (score 0):

Check this, and set according to your requirement---

```
    <?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = $field_title;

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>'.$field_title.'</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>'.$field_title.'!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th><th>Company Name</th><th>Company Registered Number</th><th>Phone Number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>'.$field_fullname.'</td><td>'.$field_companyname.'</td><td>'.$field_companynumber.'</td><td>'.$field_phonenumber.'</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: ok thanks. where would I insert the information relevant to me? also how would i send another email to the person who filled out the form? would I do something like $mail_to = 'tom@myemail.co.uk' , '.$field_email.';

Comment: @Tom check my edited code and append it more according to your requirement now :)

Comment: thanks swapnesh, ill have a play around with that. would it also be possible to send a copy of the email to the person who submitted the form? They would have already inputted their email address in the form. something like this? $mail_to = 'tom@myemail.co.uk' , '.$field_email.';

Comment: @Tom once you are done with the testing please upvote the most suitable answer..whomsoever it may belongs too

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you will have to produce an HTML email. The PHP manual has a great example you can copy and paste:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3152

Comment: thanks, how would i send another email to the person who filled out the form? would I do something like $mail_to = 'tom@myemail.co.uk' , '.$field_email.';

Answer (score 0):

instead of \n i would use

```
  <br />
```

for my personal preference.. also, for what you want to change color, wrap it in a span, and then give the span some style.

Answer (score 0):

Any of this should work

```
$body_message .= 'Title: <br />' . $field_title . "\n";

$body_message .= 'Title: ' . "\n" . $field_title . "\n";

$body_message .= 'Title: <br />' . $field_title . '<br />';
```

You can put a span tag around them so you can style accordingly.

Comment: thanks, how would i send another email to the person who filled out the form? would I do something like $mail_to = 'tom@myemail.co.uk' , '.$field_email.';

Comment: to email the person who filled out the form you will need to capture that data first. So you will need a field in the form for the user to enter their email. Then on the script you process the form you can request the value of that field and set a variable with that value. Like $mail_to = $_GET['nameOfField'] or $mail_to = $_POST['nameOfField'] depending on the method you use to process the form